# How to plot a shape above a custom variable series on tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I would like to plot a shape.triangleup above an indicator I have in a separate pane.

cpc = Indicator series based on RSI

```
hhv = highest(cpc, 20)
hhvcross = cpc > hhv[1]
plotshape(hhvcross, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, color=purple)
```

This code scales the plotting in such a way that all I can see is arrows and white space.

I tried location.absolute, but don't understand it and it didn't work either.

I'd like to see the triangleup to be plotted above the cpc line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cpc > hhv[1]` isn't capturing the cross, it's capturing that cpc is greater than hhv[1]. If your trying to put your shape at the place where they cross try `crossover(cpc,hhv)`